# Why isn't Desmos proffering the color palette to me?

Tags: desmos

Where's the color **palette, swatch, wheel (*Which is the correct term???*)** exhibited [here](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406795899533-Custom-Colors)?

[image]

I see merely 6 colors. [source](https://cl.desmos.com/t/how-to-set-the-color-of-a-graph-point-using-cl/50)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you need to create custom colors as shown in the image